# Appending column to List or Vector

Tags: java

I have stored in a List a dataset from the Database. (It contains data of a single column).

In my inner class which implements my own TableDataModel I simply convert that List to a Vector to feed the JTable. In a second column I would like to display for each row a JCheckBox (rows with ticked Checkboxes will be stored afterwards in the database).

How can I extend/append the List/Vector with the "Boolean.TRUE" or "Boolean.False" as the value for the second column?

Sorry I am bloody newbie... thanks a lot

```
class SetVehicleCategoryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Category> all = null;
    Vector<Object> tableData;
    Vector<String> tableHeaders;

    public SetVehicleCategoryTableModel(){
        initModel();
    }

    public void initModel(){
        tableData = new Vector<Object>();
        // TableModel's column names
        tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
        tableHeaders.add("Category");
        tableHeaders.add("Selection");

        // Database call
        all = new ReadCategory().allCategories();

        // TableModel's data
        // converting List<Category> -> Vector<Object> tableData

        for(Object o : all) {
            tableData.addElement(o);
            //tableData.add(,o);
            // debug:
            System.out.println("item added");

        }

        //debug:
        System.out.println(tableData.size());
        for(Object obj : tableData){
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return tableData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return tableHeaders.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){

        return tableHeaders.elementAt(column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        return tableData.elementAt(rowIndex);
        //return ((Vector<Object>) tableData.get(rowIndex)).get(columnIndex);
    }

    public void removeRow(int row) {

        tableData.removeElementAt(row);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void insertRow(Object aValue) {
        tableData.addElement(aValue);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        //fireTableRowsInserted(index, index);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){

        Category edit = (Category) tableData.elementAt(rowIndex);
        edit.setName((String) aValue);
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        //fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    // This method is used by the JTable to define the default
    // renderer or editor for each cell. For example if you have
    // a boolean data it will be rendered as a check box. A
    // number value is right aligned.

    /*@Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        //return data[0][columnIndex].getClass();
    }*/

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you're using your own TableDataModel, we'll need to see the code for that at least.  Also if you could add any attempt you have made to solve the problem yourself, it would help.

Comment: I added the source code.

Comment: The obvious question is why do you need a vector instead of a list?  Vectors are old and generally should be avoided in new code.  If you use a list you can just use `list.addAll(anoterhList)` to add the elements.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. this won't help me; anotherlist items will be added to the first vector but will still give me a one dimensional vector. But I need a 2d Vector for my table.